# Why doesn't text.value return the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

this code doesn't work, but I d'ont understand why.

HTML:

```
<button id="button">add item</button>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

JavaScript:

```
let text = document.querySelector('#text').value;
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
alert(text)
})
```

When I clicked, the 'alert' is empty - without the text I wrote.

Comment: You need to get the value in the function ``alert(text.value)``, and define the element only at the beginning ``let text = document.querySelector('#text')``. This way it takes the value at ``click`` each time.

Comment: You need to get the value **inside** the click event listener, to get what it currently is.  Not what it was on page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you declare text's value immediately without ever changing it. Once the page loads, it instantly takes the value of input with id="text", which would equal an empty string since you never had the time in the first place to type anything into it. If you set the input's 'value' attribute to say '5' for instance, the alert would always alert '5'.

In order to always get the current value in '#text', you would need to set the value of 'text' inside the event listener. So something like this:

```
<body>
    <button id="button">add item</button>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <script>
        let button = document.querySelector('#button');
        
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            let text = document.querySelector('#text').value;
            alert(text);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Now it should alert whatever you type inside the input. I'm not experienced in programming either, but I hope this helps.